# Getting error when running WSO2 API Manager with WSO2 BAM Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I got the following error when runnning WSO2 API Manager 1.3.1 to use the WSO2 BAM Server 2.0.1.

> TID: [0] [AM] [2013-05-02 18:58:40,609] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher}
>   -   Error initializing APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher}
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException:
>   Error when finding event stream definition for :
>   org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request 1.0.0

Both API Manager and BAM are running on the same machine and I changed offset to 1 in /home/jtao/api/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/conf/carbon.xml based on [Monetization of API Usage](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM131/Monetization+of+API+Usage).

I also checked that BAM_HOME/repository/conf/etc/cassandra-component.xml doesn't exist in BAM 2.0.1. as someone suggested in the answer of another question "Configuring WSO2 API Manager to use the WSO2 BAM Server"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I  ran the same scenario described in guide and it works without any error. May be your have missed a part in the configuration guide? Make sure BAM_HOME is set correctly and BAM server is started before the AM server.

The following guide too can be used to integrate AM 1.3.1 with BAM 2.0.1

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM131/Monitoring+and+Statistics

Ishara

Comment: Thanks Ishara. Could you please give me an example of your configuration, for example, api-manager.xml and master-datasources.xml for AM server, carbon.xml and master-datasources.xml for BAM server. Thanks a lot! Weili

Comment: Also, what java version you are using? Thanks.

Comment: You have to use JDK 1.6 version.

Comment: The configuration files are too long to post here as an answer. However the given reference doc explains the sequence of steps what you have to do. Did you fail in any step in running this correctly? We can help you if you post the error.

Comment: Also in addition to the given steps, also change the following entry in the api-manager.xml file under <APIKeyManager> section.  <KeyValidatorClientType>WSClient</KeyValidatorClientType><EnableThriftServer>false</EnableThriftServer>

Comment: <APIUsageTracking>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <PublisherClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher</PublisherClass>
        <ThriftPort>7612</ThriftPort>
        <BAMServerURL>tcp://localhost:7612/</BAMServerURL>
        <BAMUsername>admin</BAMUsername>
        <BAMPassword>admin</BAMPassword>
        <DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName>
        ...
</APIUsageTracking> The setting for WSO2AM_STATS_DB in master-datasources.xml under /home/jtao/api/wso2am-1.3.1/repository/conf/datasources is

Comment: <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:/home/jtao/api/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/database/APIMGTSTATS_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>

Comment: <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
         </datasource>

Comment: I got the following error after starting AM server:
[2013-05-06 17:25:01,007] ERROR - APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher Error initializing APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Error when finding event stream definition for : org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request 1.0.0

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Weili

Comment: Sorry, I have to make them into multiple comments because of the length limit for each comment. If possible, could you please send your config files on BAM and AM servers to my email at weili_wang@trimble.com? Thanks!

Comment: I also have <Offset>0</Offset> in carbon.xml under /home/jtao/api/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/conf. I added the following into master-datasources.xml under /home/jtao/api/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/conf/datasources.

Comment: <datasource>
<name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
<description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
<definition type="RDBMS">
<configuration>
<url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/APIMGTSTATS_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
<username>wso2carbon</username>
<password>wso2carbon</password>
<driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
<maxActive>50</maxActive>
<maxWait>60000</maxWait>
<testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
<validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
<validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
</configuration>
</definition></datasource>

Comment: You have to set  <Offset>1</Offset> in carbon.xml under /home/jtao/api/wso2bam-2.0.1/repository/conf. I guess that the error is there. Please re-check whether you have setup the changes according to the doc.Thanks!